# Microsoft Graph - Education APIs - Students/Teacher Relationships

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

We are using Microsoft Graph API in an education context to store data about students that have been created by teachers. We are trying to figure out a way of being able to determine:

- If a user is a student or a teacher. Based on documentation it seems this [should be possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationuser?view=graph-rest-1.0), but based on the comments on Stack Overflow and what we´ve seen, this only works if the school uses SDS and if we use Application, not Delegated permissions.
- We want to determine somehow if a pupil is taught by a teacher. We can´t see any clear way we can do this. The only way we can figure something out is to scan through all the classes of the pupil and then find those classes where the user is an owner/teaches those classes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't technically need to be using School Data Sync (SDS), but it does make the data a bit easier to work with and more consistent. This is because SDS will automatically populate the `primaryRole`, `teacher`, and `student` data each time it syncs. Without SDS, this would need to be determined and updated by your application. This is often a non-trivial exercise.

That said, there are a few ways to determine if a User is a Student or a Teacher without relying on the `primaryRole`. The more direct way is the `/taughtClasses` endpoint. This will return a collection of Classes that a User owns/teaches:

```
GET beta/education/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/taughtClasses

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.educationClass)",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "c4c1b1e9-bd8e-4ffc-acb4-e7745342bf6d",
      "description": "PrimaryTestClass",
      "displayName": "PrimaryTestClass",
      "mailNickname": "PrimaryTestClass",
      "classCode": "21001",
      "externalName": "PrimaryTestClass",
      "externalId": "21001",
      "externalSource": "sis",
      "term": {
        "externalId": "12000",
        "startDate": "2017-07-01",
        "endDate": "2018-06-30",
        "displayName": "SY1516"
      },
      "course": {
        "subject": "PrimaryTestClass",
        "courseNumber": "101",
        "description": "PrimaryTestClass",
        "displayName": "PrimaryTestClass",
        "externalId": "21001"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "8a15c9c0-13ed-464a-81ec-a6fb2d571599",
      "description": "Health Level 1",
      "displayName": "Health 1",
      "mailNickname": "fineartschool.net",
      "externalSource": "sis",
      "externalName": "Health Level 1",
      "externalId": "11019",
      "classCode": "Health 501",
      "createdBy": {
        "application": {
          "id": "a0c464d5-af1f-4bb9-bbdd-196bd577c796"
        },
        "user": {
          "id": "7cea8be3-ceec-4200-b224-4845c8e38363"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Determining which Students are taught by which Teacher is trickier. You can get the list of Classes they belong to using `beta/education/users/{id}/classes` but you would then need to iterate over *that* list to get the list of Teachers for each Class by querying `beta/education/classes/c4c1b1e9-bd8e-4ffc-acb4-e7745342bf6d/teachers?$select=id,userPrincipalName` to compile the complete list of Teachers.

As for Application vs Delegated, the Education APIs are intentionally very restrictive when it comes to Delegated scopes. This is due to the intensely sensitive nature of Student information and the understandable level of security scrutiny this data receives.